# Getting "DDL statements are not allowed in transactions " error when re-index programmatically in magento 2.2.X

Tags: magento2.2, reindex, magento2.2.6

I am working on Magento 2.2.6. As per requirement I need to do re-index on **sales_order_save_after**  event.

It is working well in Magento 2.1.X but I am getting following error on Magento 2.2.X.

> Error: CRITICAL: User Error: DDL statements are not allowed in
>   transactions in vendor/magento/framework/DB/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php on
>   line 504

Can anyone help me on the same ? I have to re-index after order complete as I need to display that order in my custom front-end page. Without re-index it is not displaying.

Comment: Did you get any solution ? I'm having same problem while reindex programatically from observer.

Comment: Any solution to this??

Comment: @David Coder did you find any solution on it. Please answer here https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/307423/error-ddl-statements-are-not-allowed-in-transactions-while-reindexing-programm if you have any idea. Actually i am facing same an error.